# Tailwind utility classes are not working inline with nextjs?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

After removing all inline tailwind classes and putting them in CSS files with @apply it works well but not inline utility classes can anybody tell me why? I'm using windows 10 and latest version of nextjs 12 and 2.2.16 version of tailwind css

Comment: Most probably because you have not configured the purge/content option properly. Add your folder structure and tailwind.config.js to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy in the new version of TailwindCss 3.0 , the tailwindconfig.js has replaced the usage of "purge" keyword to "content" . Make changes and tell if this worked